# How can I retrieve a global value in a different locale?

Tags: localization, globals

Not much to add to the question, other than I need to display a global's value in a different locale to the current locale.

Is this the best way of doing it?

```
craft.globals.getSetByHandle('localeModal').locale('es').getFieldValue('headline')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's how you would do it.

```
{{ craft.globals.getSetByHandle('localeModal').locale('es').getFieldValue('headline') }}
```

Or in shorter syntax:

```
{{ localeModal.locale('es').headline }}
```

Comment: Do you know how to make it works with Craft 3?